# Powershell recursive search and copy from input file

Tags: powershell, file-transfer

looking for a way to specify a list of possible filenames without extension and to recursively search through a folder tree and then copy found files to a new location.

Comment: Have you looked into using `FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %A IN ('DIR /S /B /A-D Filename') DO XCOPY /Y /F "%~A" "C:\NewLocationPath\"` ?

Comment: More generally, what have you tried so far? Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The files to include could be read in from a file.
Change the vars `$Include`, `$BaseFolder` and `$NewLocation` according to your needs.

```
$Include = @"
Name1
Name2
Name3
"@

$BaseFolder  = "X:\path\to\somewhere"
$NewLocation = "Y:\path\to\somewhere\else"

Get-ChildItem -Path $BaseFolder -recurse -include * | 
  Where-Object {$Include -contains $_.BaseName }|
    Copy-Iterm -Destination $NewLocation -whatif
```

If the output looks ok, remove the `-whatif` in the last line.